# Format number with thousand separators in SQL / MS Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am developing a c# windows forms application which involves connection with MS Access database. After certain query the result is shown in a datagridview. I would like the datagridview columns that hold numbers to show these with thousand separators as well as multiple decimal places.

I have tried applying the currency format to MS Access number columns but that restricts to just two decimal places.

The columns with numbers in them should be displayed with thousand separators as well as multiple decimal places.

Comment: Your grid control probably has a format parameter member at the column level, try that. If you still need help you need to update your question with more data, preferably an [mcve].

Comment: try this in query part - SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(253654252 AS MONEY), 1) AS VARCHAR)

Comment: Try searching for `datagridviewcolumn format`.

Answer (score 0):

In the DataGridView designer, open *DefaultCellStyle* of the textbox and set property *Format* (under Behaviour) to: **N2**